# how to add a refresh token to JWT auth Flask

Tags: python, flask, jwt

I do authorization through JWT. I have a code that implements the issuance of a JWT token, but how to make a refresh token. Here s my code

```
@app.route("/login", methods=['POST'])
def login():
    request_json = request.get_json()
    token = jwt.encode({
        "user": request_json.get("username"),
        "expiration": str(datetime.datetime.utcnow() + datetime.timedelta(minutes=60))
    }, str(app.config['SECRET_KEY']))
    return jsonify({
        "token": token
    })
```

```
def token_required(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def decorated(*args, **kwargs):
        token = None
        if "x-access-token" in request.headers:
            token = request.headers['x-access-token']
        if not token:
            return jsonify({
                "message": "token is required"
            }), 401
        try:
            payload = jwt.decode(token, str(app.config['SECRET_KEY']), algorithms=['HS256'])
        except Exception as ee:
            print(ee)
            return jsonify({
                "message": "invalid token"
            }), 401
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return decorated
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on what exactly you want? From what I understand you can just return what you have returned in your login with a longer expiration time.

Comment: you could issue another token.